# Validation in Adobe PDF form submitted via email?

Tags: validation, adobe, acrobat

I have a form that I created in Adobe Acrobat Professional that accepts approximately a dozen fields. I want to be able to validate phone numbers and emails using regular expressions but I'm unsure on how to do this. I know where to enter the custom script in the Validaiton tab of the field's properties but when I click on submit button nothing fires and Adobe launches the following window.

[image]

My submit action is set up like this.

[image]

Comment: Cant it be that there simply no way to enter wrong values and validation not required?

Answer (score 0):

It may not need to be done using validation.  I'm not sure if this function is available to older versions of Acrobat, but in Acrobat X Pro, if you select the **form field> right click> properties> Format> Special**   you can select pre-defined format of "Phone Number" for the phone number field  and then possible input an arbitrary mask into the arbitrary mask field for the email one.

I believe the phone number one might be limited to USA phone numbers, but it's worth a shot and might be much simpler that writing code to validate it.